# Typecasting from C++ to Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi

How would I translate this into Delphi?

```
typedef struct ext2dirent {
    EXT2_DIR_ENTRY *next;
    EXT2_DIR_ENTRY *dirbuf;
    Ext2File *parent;
    lloff_t read_bytes;     // Bytes already read
    lloff_t next_block;
} EXT2DIRENT;

typedef struct tagEXT2_DIR_ENTRY {
    uint32_t    inode;          /* Inode number */
    uint16_t    rec_len;        /* Directory entry length */
    uint8_t     name_len;       /* Name length */
    uint8_t filetype;       /* File type */
    char    name[EXT2_NAME_LEN];    /* File name */
} __attribute__ ((__packed__)) EXT2_DIR_ENTRY;


EXT2DIRENT *dirent;

int blocksize = 4096;

dirent->dirbuf = (EXT2_DIR_ENTRY *) new char[blocksize]; //<-- This line
```

I thought of doing something like this;

```
Type
  PExt2_Dir_Entry = ^Ext2_Dir_Entry;
  Ext2_Dir_Entry = packed Record
    inode: Cardinal;
    rec_len : Word;
    name_len : Byte;
    filetype : Byte;
    name : Array[0..EXT2_NAME_LEN-1] of AnsiChar;
  End;

    var
      temp : array of AnsiChar;

      if dir = NIL then
        Result := nil;

        SetLength(temp,self.block_size-1);
        dir.dirbuf := PExt2_Dir_Entry(@temp);
```

However I'm not getting the result I would expect in `dir.dirbuf`. I don't understand what the `new char` feature does in C++. But I think it might be something to do with my failure.

Comment: As side note: `char` in your line in question mean more likely a `Byte`, not `AnsiChar`. And if you are referencing a heap block of Delphi's **dynamic** array, you have to write it as `@temp[Low(temp)]` (index expr evaluates to 0, ofc).

Comment: Interesting, thanks for your input. I modified my code made in your comment, but I still don't get the desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ code line with `new` allocates `blocksize` bytes of memory and cast pointer to needed type.
Your @temp is pointer to pointer. It is not what we want.
In Delphi you may to do:

```
GetMem(dir.dirbuf, blocksize);
```

*It is not clear from code above, why allocation size is 4096 instead of SizeOf(Ext2_Dir_Entry)*

Comment: The `blocksize` is set elsewhere in the code. I used 4096 as a constant to test the code. Also your suggestion still doesn't give the desired results.

Comment: We don't know about your another code. Are you sure that all is correct?